# Ubuntu does not correctly display non-ASCII characters in Windows folder names

Tags: windows, filesystem, locale, encoding, special-characters

If I save folders in windows with special characters like ä/ö/ü or chinese characters, they will be displayed with question marks in Ubuntu. But if I write it directly in Ubuntu, it will be displayed normally. And the folder with ä/ö/ü characters there is also "invalid encoding" displayed in brackets.

Do you know how to display it normally ?

Comment: What file system is that partition formatted where the badly displayed folder names are stored? NTFS? And what are your locales/language settings on Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: I think it is formatted in vfat. In locale I get this:  
de_AT.utf8  
de_BE.utf8  
de_CH.utf8  
de_DE.utf8  
de_LI.utf8  
de_LU.utf8  
en_AG  
en_AG.utf8  
en_AU.utf8  
en_BW.utf8  
en_CA.utf8  
en_DK.utf8  
en_GB.utf8  
en_HK.utf8  
en_IE.utf8  
en_IN  
en_IN.utf8  
en_NG  
en_NG.utf8  
en_NZ.utf8  
en_PH.utf8  
en_SG.utf8  
en_US.utf8  
en_ZA.utf8  
en_ZM  
en_ZM.utf8  
en_ZW.utf8  
ja_JP.utf8  
POSIX  
zh_CN.utf8  
zh_SG.utf8

Comment: Please [edit] your post, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to mount the usb with `iocharset=utf8`.

> mount /dev/sdx /mnt/folder/ -o iocharset=utf8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) Ping me if you want an up-vote on your answer after the edit.